# how to search nested objects and group according to a field

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array that contains nested objects, and i want to filter the objects according to a particular field. Items array contains an item object, that contains some particular field like name, id, price, and vendorid. I want to sort and filter the array according to the vendorid field. For example an array like :

```
var items=[{item:{name:"cap",
                  id:"5d767e1358ad1d0ca4894592",
                  price:50, 
                  vendorid:"5d72d2a6d87c4628ba60e046"
                 },
            }
            {item:{name:"shorts",
                  price:100,
                  vendorid:"5d71c51f2092d318a1bf8f53"
                 }
            },
            {item:{name:"shoes",
                  price:90,
                  vendorid:"5d71c51f2092d318a1bf8f53"
                  }
            }
            {item:{name:"black hood",
                  price:120,
                  vendorid:"5d71c51f2092d318a1bf8f53"
                  }
            }
           ]
```

I want to create an object that outputs this :

```
results = {"5d71c51f2092d318a1bf8f53":[{name:"shorts"
                                        price:100,
                                     vendorid:"5d71c51f2092d318a1bf8f53"},
                                       {name:"shoes",    
                                        price:90,
                                     vendorid:"5d71c51f2092d318a1bf8f53"},
                                       {name:"black hood",
                                        price:120,
                                     vendorid:"5d71c51f2092d318a1bf8f53"}

                                   ],
           "5d72d2a6d87c4628ba60e046":[{name:"cap",
                                        id:"5d767e1358ad1d0ca4894592",
                                        price:50, 
                                       vendorid:"5d72d2a6d87c4628ba60e046"
                                       }
                                      ]
          }
```

The results object format is `{vendorid:[array containing objects with the same vendorid]}`.

Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to do that.

```js
var items = [{ item: { name: "cap", id: "5d767e1358ad1d0ca4894592", price: 50, vendorid: "5d72d2a6d87c4628ba60e046" } } ,{ item: { name: "shorts", price: 100, vendorid: "5d71c51f2092d318a1bf8f53" } }, { item: { name: "shoes", price: 90, vendorid: "5d71c51f2092d318a1bf8f53" } }, { item: { name: "black hood", price: 120, vendorid: "5d71c51f2092d318a1bf8f53" } } ];

let result = items.reduce((obj, currentValue) => {
  
  if (!obj[currentValue.item.vendorid]) {
    obj[currentValue.item.vendorid] = [];
  }
  
   obj[currentValue.item.vendorid].push({
     ...currentValue.item
   });
  
  return obj;
}, {});

const orderedResult = {};

// Sorting on vendorid.
Object.keys(result).sort().forEach(key => orderedResult[key] = result[key]);

console.log(orderedResult);
```

**A note on ordering of object properties:**

> As of ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), object's own properties do have order
>   for some operations, but relying on it isn't a good idea. If order is
>   important, then better to use an array or something similar.